# Fetching data from database for front-end

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on a front-end for a catalog database.  So far it is going pretty good, but by the end of this I'll have probably a million rows of items in my database.  I know this is more option based, but I wanted feedback on the best of way of doing this.

I was wondering if I should pull all records at once for a list and then use a filter type setup so it shows only items starting with A, or top rating items, then can click b and it would show all items starting with a b as option 1.  Option 2 would be fetching the new data from the database upon request.  So by default items starting with A will show then when the link/button for items b is click it will connect to the database and fetch those items.

Thoughts and options please!

PS I'm working with bootstrap/php/mysql/jquery/javascript.

Comment: It sounds like a waste of memory and bandwidth to transfer a large dataset from database to application, only then to filter it. Better to ask the database to furnish the application with only the subset in which it is interested at that time, and later request some other subset if subsequently required.  I guess this is what you mean by "Option 2"? How you should divide the data into subsets, and which subset you should show at first instance, are functional aspects of your application design that are neither on-topic for Stack Overflow nor possible to decide from the information given.

Comment: @eggyal thank you for your answer, I will not pull all data at once then.  As for the filter it was a more responsive bootstrap type filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, don't pull all million records every request.

See LIMIT and OFFSET http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

You should probably use an ORM or library that helps you with pagination

Make sure you understand SQL parameterization (for security)

I find that lists like catalogs are best served from search servers (like Solr) over databases, esp if you want search facets. MySQL does have text search though.

Comment: thank you, I did look at Solr, but it just wasn't what I was looking for at this time.  As for pagination I know that there is a purpose to use it, but I like the look of continues scrolling to few the data.  Thank you for answer the question. Thank you I will limit my pull though to a specific set of data.

Comment: Check out infinite scrolling. Once you scroll down, it will make an ajax request to server (getting next page from database) and append the new results